# Null pointer exception with values on text change listener android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-edittext, textwatcher, addtextchangedlistener

I have code to simply calculate compound interest. The calculation will change when the user edits the value in an EditText view.

```
public class CompoundInterest extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView mCompBalance;
    TextView mBalance;
    EditText mYears;
    Integer balance;
    Integer years;
    Double compbalance;
    Double interest;
    boolean isNumber;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_compound_interest);

        interest = 0.025;

        mBalance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_savingsbalance);
        mCompBalance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_interestbalance);
        mYears = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_years);
        System.out.println(mYears.getText().toString());

        Resources res = getResources();
        balance = Integer.valueOf(res.getString(R.string.savings_balance));
        mBalance.setText("£"+ balance);


        mYears.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if (mYears.getText().toString().matches("\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?")){
                    years = Integer.valueOf(mYears.getText().toString());
                    System.out.println(years);
                    isNumber =true;
                } else {
                    isNumber =false;
                }

                if (isNumber){
                    compbalance = balance*Math.pow(1+interest, years);
                    mCompBalance.setText("£"+String.format("%.2f", compbalance));
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });


    }
}
```

When I try to edit the EditText view that sets the number of years for the calculation - I get this error and the app crashes:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                    at com.###.android.citiapp.CompoundInterest$1.onTextChanged(CompoundInterest.java:63)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:8187)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:8249)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:10371)
>                                                                                    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1208)
>                                                                                    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:578)
>                                                                                    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:230)
>                                                                                    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:229)
>                                                                                    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.deleteSurroundingText(BaseInputConnection.java:251)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:459)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:93)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: The above link has some tips on how to diagnose the problem and fix it. In order for us to help you, please post the entire stack trace and show which line causes the error.

Comment: For future reference, you can maintain correct formatting in your code by highlighting it and pressing Ctrl-K. This adds four spaces at the beginning of **every** line.

Comment: on which line does the NPE happen? show full stacktrace, not only top line of it.

Comment: @VladMatvienko added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `charSequence.toString()` instead of `mYears.getText().toString()` in `onTextChanged` function. Hope it helps or specify exactly where `NullPointerException` is occurring?

Comment: Yes this worked, what did using charSequence change?

Comment: My understanding: `mYears` is not accessible inside `onTextChanged` function that's why `charSequence` is passed in parameter list.